# Python : how to extract the first substring of a string with separator into another column?

Tags: python, split, delimiter, separator

I have a dataframe with a column "CCR" whose values are as such :
"Aaaa;Bbbb;Cccc", or "Bbbb;;Cccc", or "Cccc;Bbbb;Aaaa".
I would like to take only the first part (before the ";") and put this into another column "1st CCR". I can't seem to make it work using the split function. With this code I tried, nothing happens.
Can you help ?

```
def get_1stCCR(row):
  for row in df['CCR']:
    df['1stCCR'] = row.split(";")[0]

df['CCR'].apply(get_1stCCR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following using a lambda function:

```
df['newCCR']=df['CCR'].apply(lambda x:x[0:x.index(';')])
```

If some rows don't have ';' in them, you should use:

```
df['newCCR']=df['CCR'].apply(lambda x:x[0:x.index(';') if ';' in x else None])
```

Comment: I'm getting a "ValueError: substring not found".

Comment: @Heltal Is it possible that not all your values have ";" in them?

Comment: Indeed, some only have one value and therefore no ';' at all. In that case I would like to extract that value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! How would I alter this lambda function if I were looking for a specific substring such as 'ABC' to put into my secondary column?

df['newCCR']=df['CCR'].apply(lambda x:x[0:x.index(';') if 'ABC' in x else None])